# First time Ubuntu user. 14.04 freezes

Tags: boot, 14.04, system-installation

So, I work at a computer repair shop, and there we have a bunch of hard drives just lying about, so I decided to install Linux to check it out.

I googled how to install Linux, and I ended up downloading the .iso for Ubuntu amd64.
I used the UNebootin thing to mount it on a USB, then booted off the USB, since I didn't have any CDs handy.

Anyway, I installed Ubuntu, and it seemed all fine and dandy, but when I moved the mouse a bit, the screen freezed.

I kept restarting, and the same thing kept happening.
Also, I noticed there wasn't a login screen anytime I started it.

Specs: the hard drive was a 160gb 2.5inch Hitachi HDD
Prior to installing Ubuntu, it had Windows 7 Home Premium

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing is, when the OS hangs, you reset it manually.
In this, some parts of hard disk go corrupt. so OS will do scan disk or check disk at next start.
You may be seeing the dots running for long time, this is because it is doing scan disk at the background.
When on that screen, click alt + tab. It shows that is going on in the background.

Alternate solution can be, to reinstall the OS. When reinstalling, give same drives for / and swap, but de-select the format option. It sort of repairs the installation.

It should work.